# Get value of HashMap by specific key in EL without iterating over it

Tags: jsp, hashmap, el

I want to read data from a `HashMap` using EL in a JSP page, but without the use of JSTL `<c:forEach>` or a `for` loop. How can I do this?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Just use the map key as if it were a bean property:

```
${map.key}
```

This does under the covers the same as `map.get("key")`.

---

Or via the brace notation if the key contains dots:

```
${map['key.with.dots']}
```

This does under the covers the same as `map.get("key.with.dots")`.

---

Or if the key is another variable:

```
${map[dynamicKey]}
```

This does under the covers the same as `map.get(dynamicKey)`.