# Retrieving cookie and array values in JSTL tags

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

While retrieving cookies I need to use:

```
<c:forEach items="${cookie}" var="currentCookie">  
    ${currentCookie.value.name} </br>
</c:forEach>
```

But, while using custom arrays, why we need to skip the .value function?

```
<c:forEach items="${myList}" var="myList">  
    ${myList.name} </br>
</c:forEach>
```

Cookie contains a .getValue function() which returns the content of the cookie in string format, so how does using currentCookie.value.name work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `${cookie}` points to a [`Map<String, Cookie>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) with the cookie name as map key and the [`Cookie`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html) object as map value. Every iteration over a `Map` in `<c:forEach>` gives you a [`Map.Entry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) back which in turn has [`getKey()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getKey%28%29) and [`getValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getValue%28%29) methods. Your confusion is that the `Cookie` object has in turn *also* a [`getValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#getValue%28%29) method.

```html
<c:forEach items="${cookie}" var="currentCookie">  
    Cookie name as map entry key: ${currentCookie.key}<br/>
    Cookie object as map entry value: ${currentCookie.value}<br/>
    Name property of Cookie object: ${currentCookie.value.name}<br/>
    Value property of Cookie object: ${currentCookie.value.value}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

It's a `Map<String, Cookie>` because it allows you easy direct access to cookie value when you already know the name beforehand. The below example assumes it to be `cookieName`:

```
${cookie.cookieName.value}
```

Your list example is by the way invalid. The `var` should not refer the same name as the list itself.

Comment: I suppose you meant ${cookie} instead of ${cookies}, as running it with ${cookies} outputs empty rows

Comment: Right, I just copypasted your original code, I fixed the answer :)

Comment: thanks for your help, also when we directly use cookie.cookieName.value, does it internally resolve to cookie.get(cookieName) to get the matching pair? Isn't this unusual on how EL tags function

Comment: Yes. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395308/read-data-from-hashmap-using-jstl-tag-in-jsp-without-using-for-each-or-for-loop and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info The job is by the way done  by container's builtin `MapELResolver` http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/MapELResolver.html