# Can't set a cookie with JSP

Tags: java, jsp, cookies

Can't set a cookie through JSP. But JavaScript works good.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
...//imports and taglibs
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.Cookie" %>
<%
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("testJSP", "testJSP");
    cookie.setMaxAge(365*24*60*60);
    response.addCookie(cookie);
%>
<div ...
   <span><%=request.getCookies()[0].getName() + " " + request.getCookies()[1].getName()%></span>
```

I will get a JSESSIOID and a name "test" of my cookie that I set through JS, but if I try to add

```
request.getCookies()[2].getName()
```

I'll get an "HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/issueGrid.jsp at line 18"
Also in Firebug I don't see cookie that I set from JSP.
Can you help me? Where is my problem?
Thx!

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883251/retriving-cookie-and-array-values-in-jstl-tags

Answer (score 0):

When doing `response.addCookie(cookie);` you are actually adding the cookie to the current HTTP response.

To check the cookies defined, try to avoid literal indexes and prefer looping over the list of cookies (or better use jstl `c:foreach`:

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < (request.getCookies() != null ? request.getCookies().length : 0); i++) { %>
    <li>
        <%= request.getCookies()[i].getName() + "=" + request.getCookies()[i].getValue()%>
    </li>
<% } %>
```

BTW if you try to access the cookie (your index 2) you add to the response on the same payload you won't get it, hence a NullPointerException, hence a `HTTP 500`

Comment: OK. Thx! But it doesn't solve my problem. It's a little different.
I do `response.addCookie(cookie);` then refresh the page in browser and I don't see my new cookie in firebug for example. Why it doesn't set with `response.addCookie(cookie);`? I can read cookies in JSP, but can't set it.

Comment: You probably have to try to isolate the code raising your issue. I've just create a simple project with your code creating the cookie, my loop and it appears.

Comment: In firebug in the network tab, you should see the `Set-Cookie` header in the response.