# JSTL - accessing cookies

Tags: java, jsp, cookies, jstl

**Hello everyone,**

I was just wondering whether it's possible to access all the stored cookies like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${cookie}" var="currentCookie" varStatus="lp">  
<tr><td>${cookie[lp.index].key} </td></tr>
</c:forEach>
```

if not, is there any way I could somehow itterate over cookies and other array in one loop?

```
<c:forEach items="${cookie}" var="currentCookie" varStatus="lp">  
<tr><td>${CurrentCookie.key} </td></tr>
<tr><td>${MyArray[lp.index].name} </td></tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Thanks for any suggestions,
Wrack

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can interate over cookies using JSTL for each, its similar like iterating over a map.
Similar question [Retrieving cookie and array values in JSTL tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883251/retriving-cookie-and-array-values-in-jstl-tags)

Comment: Hi Karna , thanks for your answer, the thing with foreach  is that it returns the values in exactly reverse order.. Any idea how I could possibly fix that?

Comment: I don't see how it returns the values in exactly reverse order. Cookies are stored in an unordered map so have no natural ordering. Can you expand this point. Thanks.

Comment: just forget about my previous question, is there a way I could itterate over an array and cookies at the same time? SOmething like..


    <c:forEach items="${array}" var="arr" varStatus="lp">  
<tr><td>${arr.v_val} </td></tr>
<tr><td>${cookie[lp.index].key} </td></tr>
</c:forEach>

Comment: @Wracker: Code you have mentioned in question should work fine. What issue/exception you are facing?

Comment: well it doesn't return anything as if the cookies didn't exist.

Comment: @Wracker: Show code which adds `MyArray` to response? Also what is the type of `MyArray`?

Comment: it's just a ***String [] MyArray***  the ***cookie*** object on the other hand is a map<> . So what I'm trying to do, is to iterate over these two objects in one loop. But obviously it's not working becuase it's likely not possible to iterate the ***cookie*** object as shown below

`<% String[] MyArray=new String[4];
MyArray[0]="null";
MyArray[1]="one";
MyArray[2]="two";
MyArray[3]="three";  %>

<c:forEach begin="0" end="${fn:length(cookie}" var="itr">  
<tr><td>${cookie[$itr].key} </td></tr>
<tr><td>${MyArray[itr]} </td></tr>
</c:forEach>`