# How to put the value of a cookie into a variable of type <c:set> from JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, cookies, struts2

How can I get the value of the following cookie and put it into variable Cli?

```
<% Cookie cookies[] = request.getCookies();
    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        if (cookies[j].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Jack")) {
             <c:set var="Cli" value="cookies[j].getValue()"/>              
        }
    }    
%>
```

Comment: Avoid scriptlets at all costs. Use EL and JSTL exclusively in JSPs.

Comment: Then see [here](http://www.journaldev.com/2064/jsp-expression-language-el-example-tutorial).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis would you give me an example as solution?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially using the goods from [Retrieving cookie and array values in JSTL tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883251/retriving-cookie-and-array-values-in-jstl-tags):

```
<c:forEach items="${cookie}" var="currentCookie">  
  <c:if test="${currentCookie.value.name == 'Jack'}">
    <c:set var="Cli" value="currentCookie.value.value"/>
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```