# Access a cookie as a dynamic variable with JSTL

Tags: cookies, jstl

I'm hoping someone can give me a few pointers.  I've tried a few iterations of accessing dynamic variables with JSTL, but I can't get it to work with cookie.

How can I use a dynamic variable to access the cookie name and have jstl expose the value?

```
<fmt:message key="my.app.cookieName" bundle="${secProps}" var="cookieNameFromProps"/>
${cookie.<cookieNameFromProps>.value}
```

Comment: My reputation is not high enough to answer the question so quickly:

Figures... I post a question and then figure it out on my own shortly there after!


Because cookie is a Map under the covers you can access it in the following manner
    
<fmt:message key="my.app.cookieName" bundle="${secProps}" var="cookieNameFromProps"/>
<c:out value="${cookie[cookieNameFromProps].value}"/> 

I used this as a reference:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395308/read-data-from-hashmap-using-jstl-tag-in-jsp-without-using-for-each-or-for-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figures... I post a question and then figure it out on my own shortly there after!

Because cookie is a Map under the covers you can access it in the following manner

```
<fmt:message key="my.app.cookieName" bundle="${secProps}" var="cookieNameFromProps"/>
<c:out value="${cookie[cookieNameFromProps].value}"/>
```

I used this as a reference:
[Read data from HashMap using JSTL tag in JSP without using for each or for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395308/read-data-from-hashmap-using-jstl-tag-in-jsp-without-using-for-each-or-for-loop)